# Nolearn/Lasagne neural network not starting training

Tags: python, theano, lasagne, nolearn

I am using `Theano 0.7`, `nolearn 0.6adev` and `lasagne 0.2.dev1` to train a neural net on GPU (in an `IPython 3.2.1` notebook). However, because of the first layer (`'reduc'`), the following network does not start training, aven after waiting a few hours:

```
import theano
from lasagne import layers
from lasagne.updates import nesterov_momentum
from nolearn.lasagne import NeuralNet
from nolearn.lasagne import BatchIterator
from lasagne import nonlinearities
from lasagne import init
import numpy as np

testNet = NeuralNet(
    layers=[(layers.InputLayer, {"name": 'input', 'shape': (None, 12, 1000, )}),

            (layers.Conv1DLayer, {"name": 'reduc', 'filter_size': 1, 'num_filters': 4, 
                                  "nonlinearity":nonlinearities.linear,}),

            (layers.Conv1DLayer, {"name": 'conv1', 'filter_size': 25, 'num_filters': 100,
                                 'pad': 'same', }),
            (layers.MaxPool1DLayer, {'name': 'pool1', 'pool_size': 5, 'stride': 3}),



            (layers.Conv1DLayer, {"name": 'conv2', 'filter_size': 15, 'num_filters': 100,
                                 'pad': 'same', 
                                  'nonlinearity': nonlinearities.LeakyRectify(0.2)}),

            (layers.MaxPool1DLayer, {'name': 'pool2', 'pool_size': 5, 'stride': 2}),

            (layers.Conv1DLayer, {"name": 'conv3', 'filter_size': 9, 'num_filters': 100,
                                 'pad': 'same', 
                                  'nonlinearity': nonlinearities.LeakyRectify(0.2)}),

            (layers.MaxPool1DLayer, {'name': 'pool3', 'pool_size': 2}),

            (layers.Conv1DLayer, {"name": 'conv4', 'filter_size': 5, 'num_filters': 20,
                                 'pad': 'same', }),

            (layers.Conv1DLayer, {"name": 'conv5', 'filter_size': 3, 'num_filters': 20,
                                 'pad': 'same',}),


            (layers.DenseLayer, {"name": 'hidden1', 'num_units': 10, 
                                 'nonlinearity': nonlinearities.rectify}),

            (layers.DenseLayer, {"name": 'output', 'nonlinearity': nonlinearities.sigmoid, 
                                 'num_units': 5})
           ],

    # optimization method:
    update=nesterov_momentum,
    update_learning_rate=5*10**(-3),
    update_momentum=0.9,

    regression=True,  
    max_epochs=1000,
    verbose=1,
    )

testNet.fit(np.random.random([3000, 12, 1000]).astype(np.float32), 
            np.random.random([3000, 5]).astype(np.float32))
```

If I comment out the first layer, the training starts in a few seconds. Training more complicated networks is not a problem either. Any idea of what's causing the issue?

**Edit**: oddly enough, if I remove `conv4` and `conv5`, the training also starts within a reasonable time.

**Edit2**: what's even stranger is, if I change the size of the filters to 10 in the layer `reduc`, then the training starts in a reasonable amount of time. If after that I stop the cell's execution, change this value to 1, and reexecute the cell, the training goes fine...

Finally I've started using another framework, but if someone's interested, [here's the link to the thread](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/lasagne-users/not$20starting/lasagne-users/XR-jmU1pMWc/Erym1kOhBQAJ) I started on the lasagne user group.